# How to select column with highest count of a certain value

Tags: python

How do I return the column name with the highest count of value "GPE"? In this case I want my output to just be "text" because that column has two rows of 'GPE' while column text2 has 1 and column text3 has 0.

Code:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
text = [["Canada", 'University of California has great research', "non-location"],["China", 'MIT is at Boston', "non-location"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['text', 'text2', 'text3'])

col_list = df.columns # obtains the columns of the dataframe

for col in col_list:
    df["".join(col)] = df[col].apply(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(x).ents)]) # combine the ent_<<col_name>> as the new columns which contain the named entities.
df
```

Desired output:

```
text
```

Comment: Not sure if what you are looking for is value_counts: `df[col].value_counts()[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`values_count()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).
Your code should look like:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
text = [["Canada", 'University of California has great research', "non-location"],["China", 'MIT is at Boston', "non-location"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['text', 'text2', 'text3'])

col_list = df.columns # obtains the columns of the dataframe

maxGPE = 0
index = ''
for col in col_list:
    newGPE = df[col].apply(lambda x: x in nlp(x).ents).sum()
    if newGPE > maxGPE: 
        index = col 
        maxGPE = newGPE
print(index)
```

Comment: Appreciate the response again, however this time I am getting this error: 'Argument 'other' has incorrect type (expected spacy.tokens.span.Span, got str)'